# Bold a number from where first instance of number above 0 is found - PHP

Tags: php

I have long decimal numbers that I'd like to make easier to read. There's many 0's involved and I would like to bold the end of the string from where the numbers stop being just 0's. The number will always have 8 decimal places, no more, no less. It's worth noting that I would like any trailing zeros to also be bold, I don't just want to avoid bolding 0 as a whole.

Example:

Before - 0.00004320

After - 0.0000**4320**

Any help or pointers in the right direction much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using a loop and some string manipulation:

```
function doTheThing($number) {
    $length = strlen($number);
    $period = strpos($number, '.') + 1;
    for ($i = $period; $i < $length; $i++) {
        if ($number[$i] !== '0') {
            $number = substr($number, 0, $i).'<b>'.substr($number, $i).'</b>';
            break;
        }
    }
    return $number;
}
echo doTheThing('0.00004320');
```

Or you can do it using a regular expression replacement:

```
function doTheThing($number) {
    return preg_replace('/^(\d+\.0*)(\d+)$/', '$1<b>$2</b>', $number);
}
echo doTheThing('0.00004320');
echo doTheThing(sprintf('%.8f', 0.00004320)); // if your number is not a string
```